# Путь в переменную через кнопку

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Вообщем проблема такая: я ввожу в текстбокс путь + файл(пусть будет D:\1.txt). При нажатии кнопки это все присваивается переменной(допустим wr).

```
procedure Form1.button6_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var wr:string;
begin
  wr:=textBox1.Text;
end;
```

Запись в файл информации будет такого типа:

```
 AssignFile(F, wr); 
 Append(F);
 write(F,textBox1.Text);
 CloseFile(F);
```

Дело в том, что ввод пути и запись в файл информации находятся в разных формах. Может надо сделать эту переменную общей? Я насчет этого не в курсе. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Ребят, никто не вкурсе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на первый взгляд есть два варианта:

1. сделать так, чтобы форма на которой вы вводите путь возвращала это значение на форму, которая ее вызвала (я так понимаю, что путь именно там и нужен)
2. сделать переменную пути общедоступной (не самый лучший вариант)

---

**UPD** первый пункт.

Есть у вас две формы: form1 и form2.
В form1 у вас какой-то функционал, которому нужны данные, а в form2 нужно получить эти данные и передать в form1.

Для этого пишите в form2 функцию открытия. Эта функция будет возвращать нужные для form1 данные. Допустим, нам надо получить строку:

```
function Form2.MyOpen(): string;
begin
  ... // тут может быть какая-то инициализация
  showModal();  // тут вы МОДАЛЬНО открываете форму и делаете на ней все, что вам нужно и заносите данные в итоговую переменную, которая вернет их на form1
  ... // этот код начнет действовать только когда форма закроется 
  result:= resultString; // тут происходит возвращение значения на form1
end;
```

а на form1 вызываете этот метод:

```
procedure Form1.GetStringFromForm2();
var
 neededString: string;
begin
  ...
  neededString:= Form2.MyOpen();
  ...
end;
```

Реализация может и не идеальная, но простая и работает.

Comment: @teanЫЧ можете обьяснить первый пункт?
Просто я со вчерашнего дня в больнице(после операции) и доступа к ноуту не будет как минимум неделю

Comment: @Sin2p расписал все.  
PS. выздоравливайте

Comment: @teanЫЧ спасибо)
Надеюсь все быстро пройдет